# draw double arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a double arrow like below:
[image]

How should I do it with tikz?

I try below code but it's not as expected:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.arrows}
\definecolor{fillcolor}{HTML}{DDE776}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{arr/.style={single arrow, draw=black, very thick, fill=fillcolor,
    minimum width = 10pt, single arrow head extend=30pt,
    inner xsep=0pt,
    }}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (2,2);
    \node[arr,fit=(a) (b)] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: In the [`shapes.arrows` library](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.5) there also exists a `double arrow` shape which is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you need a `\node` or (considering your code snippet) a path with arrows? Maybe have a look at this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620715/47927, or also at the various answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653129/47927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new answer is inspired from one answer of Jasper Habicht to a different question.
You enter in the first two lines of code the the four coordinates of point A and B. The code make all calculus for the slope of double arrow from point A to point B.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc}

\tikzset{
    MyLongArrow/.style args={#1 -- #2}{
        insert path={let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$) in}, 
        single arrow, draw=black, minimum width=15mm, minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, inner sep=0mm, single arrow head extend=1mm, double arrow head extend=1mm
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\xs}{-1} % x coord of point A
        \newcommand{\ys}{-2} % y coord  coordof point A
        \newcommand{\xe}{10} % x coord of point B
        \newcommand{\ye}{3} % y of point B
        \newcommand{\ang}{atan((\ye-\ys)/(\xe-\xs))} % slope of segment AB
        \coordinate (a) at (\xs,\ys); % point A 
        \coordinate (b) at (\xe,\ye); % point B
        \draw[gray!20] (a) grid (b);
        \path (a) -- (b) node[midway, MyLongArrow={a -- b},fill=cyan!20,double arrow,rotate=\ang] {From point A to point B};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output for points A(-1,-2) and B(10,3):

[image]

The grid is only for control, you can comment the relative line.
If you dont want the text inside the double arrow change the last line of the code this way:

```
\path (a) -- (b) node[midway, MyLongArrow={a -- b},fill=cyan!20,double arrow,rotate=\ang] {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.arrows}
\definecolor{fillcolor}{HTML}{DDE776}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[fill=fillcolor,rotate=45,yscale=.5,xscale=.5] (-3,-3)--(-5,0)--(-3,3)--(-3,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(5,0)--(3,-3)--(3,-1)--(-3,-1)--cycle;
        \node[rotate=45,cyan] at (0,0) {\Huge freccia}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

You can make a newcommand to define a generic double arrow (with the same base points) and add a parameter for:
color,
rotation angle,
xscale,
yscale,
text inside,
...

**EDIT**: For example you can have this double arrow

[image]

with some minimal changes in the code proposed before:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[fill=fillcolor,rotate=120,yscale=.5] (-3,-3)--(-5,0)--(-3,3)--(-3,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(5,0)--(3,-3)--(3,-1)--(-3,-1)--cycle;
        \node[rotate=120,red] at (0,0) {\Huge freccia}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

or this one

[image]

with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[draw,line width=2pt,fill=fillcolor,rotate=-30,yscale=.5] (-3,-3)--(-5,0)--(-3,3)--(-3,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(5,0)--(3,-3)--(3,-1)--(-3,-1)--cycle;
        \node[rotate=-30,red] at (0,0) {\Huge freccia}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good but how to draw the double arrow from point A to point B? Just like draw a arrow between two point?

Comment: Sorry, at moment I can't answer to your question.